# Why does changing Solution Platforms stop Partial Classes from being seen?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I've got a program which I'm maintaining, which was written by the guy I replaced at this company.

There is an older version of the software which works fine on all of our deployment platforms, but the version I am trying to push out is working fine on 32-bit desktop installations, but is crashing-and-burning when it attempts to access Crystal Reports and Informix installed DLLs on a 64-bit machine, running terminal server sessions (yeah, I know, could I change anything more about the deployment platform?)

One of the suggested avenues of investigation was changing the solution platform from "Any CPU" to x86.

On attempting to do this, Visual Studio seems to stop being able to connect the partial classes constructed by XAML objects, with objects declaring that they have no "InitializeComponent" methods, and then failing on down the line until I reach the maximum number of errors.

Oddly, changing the solution platform, and then rebuilding in Expression Blend compiles just fine. Changing the platform back to AnyCPU makes the problem disappear. All projects have compile and debug configurations set to Active. I can't see any reason why simply changing the targeted platform would stop the XAML from generating partial classes (or whatever the *actual* problem is...)

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Okay, it seems to be that there are some external DLLs to the project, and that *those* are the cause of what I'd call the first-level compilation failure, as they don't seem to contain any classes once the target platform has switched.

In VS2008, this causes the cascading failure of *absolutely nothing working at all*, as described above, but at one point I somehow managed to import the project to VS2010 with only those errors in place (missing classes, etc.), *without* the rest of the project imploding.

I'm now working on reconstructing those classes from those DLLs, and hopefully will be able to get together a project that will compile on multiple target platforms by the end of the day. Hopefully...

Leaving this here in case someone else ever has a similar problem, as the solution to this has definitely not been immediately obvious.

I'm still not sure why the whole of the rest of the project implodes under VS2008, or what I did to cause the

Comment: You are right, the platform target setting should have no effect whatsoever on compiling xaml.  In case it helps, only the setting on the EXE project matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Copying my EDIT above, so that the question is answered:*

Okay, it seems to be that there are some external DLLs to the project, and that those are the cause of what I'd call the first-level compilation failure, as they don't seem to contain any classes once the target platform has switched.

In VS2008, this causes the cascading failure of absolutely nothing working at all, as described above, but at one point I somehow managed to import the project to VS2010 with only those errors in place (missing classes, etc.), without the rest of the project imploding.

I'm now working on reconstructing those classes from those DLLs, and hopefully will be able to get together a project that will compile on multiple target platforms by the end of the day. Hopefully...

Leaving this here in case someone else ever has a similar problem, as the solution to this has definitely not been immediately obvious.

I'm still not sure why the whole of the rest of the project implodes under VS2008, or what I did to cause the

Answer (score 0):

> One of the suggested avenues of investigation was changing the solution platform from "Any CPU" to x86.

If you are referencing native DLLs directly or indirectly they must match the execution "bitness" of the loading process.

On a 32bit system your application will run 32bit (of course) and load 32 bit versions of those third party libraries.

But on a 64bit system are there *64bit* versions of Informix and Crystal Reports?

Build as x86 only unless you will benefit from running as a 64bit process (unlikely), it will save testing everything twice.

PS. Ensure you do a full rebuild when changing the platform setting, so any existing intermediate files are deleted first.